# Processing a nested dict and list Json to a DataFrame

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a json object like this:

```
[{"ID": "101",
  "OagCode": "1000",
  "house": [{"from": [{"CneeCode":"30100"}], "ShprCode": "20100"}]},
 {"ID": "102",
  "OagCode": "1001",
  "house": [{"from": [{"CneeCode":"30101"}], "ShprCode": "20101"},
            {"from": [{"CneeCode":"30102"}], "ShprCode": "20102"},
            {"from": [{"CneeCode":"30103"}], "ShprCode": "20103"}]}]
```

I want to convert this json to a dataframe in such a way that the interior list expands and form a dataframe with proper values as follows:

```
+-----+---------+----------+----------+
| ID  | OagCode | CneeCode | ShprCode |
+-----+---------+----------+----------+
| 101 | 1000    | 30100    | 20100    |
| 102 | 1001    | 30101    | 20101    |
| 102 | 1001    | 30102    | 20102    |
| 102 | 1001    | 30103    | 20103    |
+-----+---------+----------+----------+
```

Is there a way to convert the above stated json to dataframe without using loops?
I have tried *orient* and it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(j,record_path='house',meta=['ID','OagCode'])
print (df)
  CneeCode ShprCode   ID OagCode
0    30100    20100  101    1000
1    30101    20101  102    1001
2    30102    20102  102    1001
3    30103    20103  102    1001
```

Comment: @thanatoz - Unfortunately [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html?highlight=json_normalize#normalization) is poor, some info I found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/quick-tutorial-flatten-nested-json-in-pandas)